# Spring Boot and Hibernate: for org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

I'm setting up a Spring Boot/Hibernate project for simple CRUD operation. For that I took help from several online tutorials and written the following code. But seems there is some version mismatch or similar dependencies in my POM.xml which I am unable to understand.

I getting a MAVEN build failure each time.

**pom.xml** dependecies:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.22</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

**HibernateConfigApplication.java**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class HibernateConfigApplication {

  @Autowired
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //SpringApplication.run(HibernateConfigApplication.class, args);
    Connection conn = null;
    SessionFactory sessionfactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    if (sessionfactory != null) {
      System.out.println("Session Established");
      try {
        Object obj = Class.forName("oracle.driver.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        System.out.println("*************");
        System.out.println("obj" + obj);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Where is your oracle JDBC driver");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
      }

      System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered");
      Session session = null;

      try {
        session = sessionfactory.openSession();
      } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Exception while getting session");
        t.printStackTrace();
      }

      if (session == null) {
        System.out.println("session Registered is null");
      }

      SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactoryImplementation = (SessionFactoryImplementor) session.getSessionFactory();
      ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = sessionFactoryImplementation.getConnectionProvider();

      try {
        Connection connection = connectionProvider.getConnection();
        if (connection != null) {
          System.out.println("*********************");
          System.out.println("Connection Established");
          System.out.println("*********************");
        }

      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      session.close();
    }
  }
}
```

The specific error are as follows:
I am unable to understand how to correct the classpath of the application so that it contains a single, compatible version

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.dao.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.java:49)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(Z)V

The method's class, org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-dao/2.0.8/spring-dao-2.0.8.jar!/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-dao/2.0.8/spring-dao-2.0.8.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor

2019-07-04 08:13:22.267 ERROR 6976 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@55141def] to prepare test instance [com.example.hibernateConfig.HibernateConfigApplicationTests@5b56b654]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365) [surefire-junit4-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273) [surefire-junit4-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159) [surefire-junit4-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) [surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) [surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) [surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) [surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/dao/PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:228) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:721) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:534) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:119) ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(Z)V
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.dao.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.java:49) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 17.466 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.hibernateConfig.HibernateConfigApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(com.example.hibernateConfig.HibernateConfigApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/dao/PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(Z)V
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(Z)V
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(Z)V

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   HibernateConfigApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load App...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 25.714 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-04T08:13:23+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project HibernateConfig: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projects\HibernateConfig\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Remove the all the dependencies but the `org.springframework.boot` and `h2` dependencies.  All the others you don't need or are already manaaged by Spring Boot. Also you are using Spring so please don't use a `HibernateUtil` but let Spring properly configure and inject your`SessionFactory`.

Answer (score -1):

1. First of all create Spring boot application via https://start.spring.io/.
2. Chose Dependencies WEB,JPA,Actuator,Devtools
3. Then use EntityManager